# Optimise a if-else condition

Tags: php, if-statement

Suppose there are two arrays `$a, $b`. At any given point at least one of them is not empty or both are not empty.

How do I optimise the following condition

```
if(!$a)
{
  #TASK A
}
if(!b)
{
  #TASK B
}

if ($a['item']<$b['item'])
{
   #TASK A
}
else
{
  #TASK B
}
```

I don't want TASK A and B to be repeated twice in the program.

Comment: i meant empty. edited the question

Comment: Use two functions? `task_a();` and `task_b():`?

Comment: Can't you initialize `$a` and `$b` to a prototype if they are empty?

Comment: What's the type of `$a['item']`? Is it always a number? Can it be negative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(!$a || ($b && ($a['item'] < $b['item']))){
// task A
}
else{
// task B
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!$a || ($b && ($a['item'] < $b['item']))){
  // task A

}elseif(!$b || ($a && ($a['item'] >= $b['item']))){
  // task B
}
```

If the variables may not be set, use `empty()` or `isset()`

Comment: The second `elseif` is redundant. The first condition already covers the assertions for task a; logically, therefore, not(task a) == task b.

Answer (score 0):

This will work, but it may not be optimal. But the code is not really clear. Do TaskA and TaskB modify $a and $b?

```
$aDone = false; 
$bDone = false;

if(!$a)
{
  #TASK A
  $aDone = true; 
}
if(!b)
{
  #TASK B
  $bDone = true;
}

if ($a['item'] < $b['item'])
{
   if (!$aDone)
   {
      #TASK A
   }
}
else 
{
   if (!$bDone)
   {
     #TASK B
   }
}
```